# Looking for a linear actuator that can carry a transverse load. Does such a product exist?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, actuator

I am looking for a product that works like a linear actuator where you can control how far it extends but it can also hold a transverse load at the furthest point of extension.

What I am looking for would be similar to common consumer models such as [this one found on Amazon](https://amzn.to/3At7ynu).

It should be mounted on one end and still be able to hold the load of about 10 lbs at a distance of 45 inches (1150mm,) basically a giant cantilever beam. Does such a product exist?

Comment: The link is for an opto-isolated relay, not a linear actuator.  Since the mechanical (not electrical) properties are your main concern, have you tried the Engineering stack?

Comment: @JRE why the affiliate link?  -  that will expire in a few hours and leave the post broken again!

Comment: you'll probably need to combine two products to get the features you need,  maybe start with the extendable support and then figure out how to motorise it,

Comment: @Jasen:  I didn't change the link.  I only changed the format of the link.  The site itself seems to play games with the Amazon links.

Comment: You may search "ROBO cylinder"